# Count table rows

Tags: mysql

What is the MySQL command to retrieve the count of records in a table?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fooTable;
```

will count the number of rows in the table.

See the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html).

Comment: Is it any faster when I use name of indexed column instead of * ?
Like this: SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `tablename`

Comment: Only slightly.  I got a 21961904 row table which his COUNT queried in 115 sec, while using the ID took 107 sec.

Comment: COUNT(\*) is a strict language definition. You will get a parse error if you try COUNT (\*)  note the space

Comment: You can do `COUNT(1)`, this will be the fastest way.

Comment: What is the best way for using COUNT() to write a variable in PHP? Do I  do "...COUNT(*) AS rowCount..." in the SQL, does it use $results->num_rows, or is there a way to call this result directly?

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient or less computationally intensive to count a single column instead of ALL columns???

Comment: @Nosajimiki once you execute the prepared statement and fetch the results... `$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`... you can then call it by `$result["COUNT(*)"];`

Comment: COUNT(*) function without a WHERE clause or additional columns, will perform very fast on MyISAM tables because the number of rows is stored in the table_rows column in the tables table of the information_schema database.

For transactional storage engines such as InnoDB, storing an exact row count is problematic because InnoDB does not keep an internal count of rows in a table. 

Source: https://www.navicat.com/en/company/aboutus/blog/695-getting-row-counts-in-mysql-part-1

Comment: InnoDB handles SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT COUNT(1) operations in the same way. There is no performance difference.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 98):

Because nobody mentioned it:

```
show table status;
```

lists all tables along with some additional information, including estimated rows for each table. This is what phpMyAdmin is using for its database page.

This information is available in MySQL 4, probably in MySQL 3.23 too - long time prior information schema database.

The number shown is **estimated for InnoDB and TokuDB** but it is absolutely correct for MyISAM and Aria (Maria) storage engines.

Per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html):

> The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the
> exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is
> an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40%
> to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate
> count.

This also is fastest way to see the row count on MySQL, because query like:

```
select count(*) from table;
```

Doing full table scan what could be very expensive operation that might take hours on large high load server. It also increase disk I/O.

The same operation might block the table for inserts and updates - this happen only on exotic storage engines.

InnoDB and TokuDB are OK with table lock, but need full table scan.

Comment: This looks like the most efficient way to count rows. I wonder why it is not the answer? I'm using InnoDB. With table lock, the number of rows should be exact right?

Comment: for innodb it is **estimated**. but you can use it in some cases "Our website have xxx members", "We detected xxx results similar to yours" and so on.

Comment: I am not sure. but for Innodb is not real count. But is quite useful for million row tables.

Comment: Going through tables to count each row to get a row count is rather ridiculous. So I prefer this answer as well.

Answer (score 37):

We have another way to find out the number of rows in a table without running a `select` query on that table.

Every MySQL instance has information_schema database. If you run the following query, it will give complete details about the table including the **approximate** number of rows in that table.

```
select * from information_schema.TABLES where table_name = 'table_name'\G
```

Comment: Is this faster as well on a MyISAM table since MyISAM is storing the number of rows?

Comment: I never tested this on MyISAM.

Comment: Why does someone want to see APPROXIMATE number of rows? WTF

Comment: @Raymond It's reasonable that someone may just trying to get an estimate for the sake of decision making, but doesn't need an exact count. In my experience, this is a more common scenario in a production environment, than an exact number.

Answer (score 6):

Simply:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tablename`
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select count(*) from YourTable
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have several fields in your table and your table is huge, it's better **DO NOT USE** `*` because of it load all fields to memory and using the following will have better performance

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM fooTable;
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179969/what-is-better-in-mysql-count-or-count1  COUNT(1) may actually be much slower for MyISAM.

Comment: @jcoffland you can try t by myself, especially when you have a join or where conditions is will be much much faster than count(*).

Answer (score 3):

Just do a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

You can specify conditions with a Where after that

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE eye_color='brown';
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by *Santosh*, I think this query is suitably fast, while not querying all the table.

**To return integer result** of number of data records, for a specific *tablename* in a particular *database*:

```
select TABLE_ROWS from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database' 
AND table_name='tablename';
```

Comment: This may return an estimated number of rows.  In one example, I got 55,940,343 rows using COUNT(*) but 56,163,339 using this method so it was off by more than 200k.

Comment: @jcoffland, I mentioned the answer by _ Santosh_ above which states the result is **approximate**. My answer is a more detailed practical query. Its quite clear across answers if you want precise count use `count(*)` with performance awareness

Answer (score 2):

If you have a primary key or a unique key/index, the faster method possible (Tested with 4 millions row tables)

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM "database.tablename" WHERE Key_Name=\"PRIMARY\"
```

and then get cardinality field (it is close to instant)

Times where from 0.4s to 0.0001ms

Comment: This is brilliant! Counted rows for an unusable table.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT count(*) as toplam FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='ICERIK' AND post_id=".$id;
$total = 0;
$sqls = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if ( $sqls ) {
    $total = mysql_result($sqls, 0);
};
echo "Total:".$total;`
```

Comment: This answer is outdated, mysql_result is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in PHP 7.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You have to use count()  returns the number of rows that matches a 
specified criteria

```
select count(*) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be convenient to select count with filter by indexed field. Try this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE key < anything;
```