# What is better in MYSQL count(*) or count(1)?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

> **Related (SQL Server):** [Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Could you please tell me what is better in performance (MySQL)? Count(*) or count(1)?

Comment: That's not a dupe. It's specifically for SQL Server, this is for MySQL. I have no idea if the _answers_ will be the same but the questions are definitely different.

Comment: @phil On the other hand, that question's about SQL Server, and this one is about MySQL. I know the answer is the same, but does that mean the question's the same? (@paxdiablo ..."they chorused." :) )

Comment: @pax There's comments on that question regarding MySQL too

Comment: That may be true but people looking for questions with the `[mysql]` search term will not get that one back. The close reason is "question is a dupe", not "there's some crossover with a similar question". Voting to reopen.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't thought it's answered. Thanks.

Comment: I object to the closing on account of claiming `3 + 7` is a dupe of `sqrt(100)`, even if both answers are `10`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is a MySQL answer.

They perform exactly the same - unless you are using MyISAM, then a special case for `COUNT(*)` exists. I always use `COUNT(*)` anyway.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count

> For `MyISAM` tables, `COUNT(*)` is optimized to return very quickly if the
> `SELECT` retrieves from one table, no other columns are retrieved, and
> there is no `WHERE` clause. For example:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student;
> ```
>
> This optimization only applies to `MyISAM`
> tables, because an exact row count is stored for this storage engine
> and can be accessed very quickly. `COUNT(1)` is only subject to the same
> optimization if the first column is defined as `NOT NULL`.

---

###EDIT
Some of you may have missed the dark attempt at humour. I prefer to keep this as a non-duplicate question for any such day when MySQL will do something different to SQL Server.  So I threw a vote to reopen the question (with a clearly wrong answer).

The above MyISAM optimization applies equally to

```
COUNT(*)
COUNT(1)
COUNT(pk-column)
COUNT(any-non-nullable-column)
```

So the real answer is that they are **always** the same.

Comment: Totally not agree with U - 600 000 rows benchmark gives:
`mysql> select count(1) from users;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|   596465 |
+----------+
1 row in set (5.89 sec)`

`mysql> select count(*) from users;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   596465 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)`
engine=innodb
PS love practice =)

Comment: @zeusakm Now run it a third time. You've just benchmarked caching!