# MySQL COUNT(*) not counting result rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Simplified schema of *m:n* relation implementing a subscription model:

```
CREATE TABLE c (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(32)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE t (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(32)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE c2t (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cid INT(11) NOT NULL,
  tid INT(11) NOT NULL,
  dateStart DATE NULL,
  dateEnd DATE NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

INSERT INTO c (name) VALUES ('mike'),('carl'),('suzy');

INSERT INTO t (name) VALUES ('plan1'),('plan2'),('plan3'),('plan4');

INSERT INTO c2t (cid, tid, dateStart, dateEnd) VALUES
  (1, 1, '2014-01-01', '2014-07-31'),
  (1, 2, '2014-08-01', '2015-07-31'),
  (1, 1, '2015-08-01', null),
  (1, 3, '2015-09-01', null),

  (2, 1, '2014-01-01', '2015-07-31'),
  (2, 2, '2015-08-01', '2015-09-30'),
  (2, 3, '2015-09-30', null),

  (3, 1, '2014-01-01', '2014-12-31'),
  (3, 2, '2014-01-01', '2014-12-31'),
  (3, 3, '2015-01-01', '2015-10-31'),
  (3, 4, '2015-01-01', '2015-10-31');
```

I've developed a query to find the c's who have active subscriptions of t's:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM c
LEFT JOIN c2t ON c.id = c2t.cid
  AND NOW() BETWEEN COALESCE(dateStart, '0000-00-00')
    AND COALESCE(dateEnd, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY c2t.cid
HAVING COUNT(c2t.id) > 0;
```

Result as expected:

```
id  name
1   mike
2   carl
```

The problem arises when I try to count the result rows. The query is almost identical, I've just dropped in a COUNT(*):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM c
LEFT JOIN c2t ON c.id = c2t.cid
  AND NOW() BETWEEN COALESCE(dateStart, '0000-00-00')
    AND COALESCE(dateEnd, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY c2t.cid
HAVING COUNT(c2t.id) > 0;
```

Result:

```
`COUNT(*)`
2
1
```

Expected result would be a single row containing the number of rows found (2). I can only assume that the GROUP BY is interfering, but have no idea how to work around. Explanations are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything with subquery and use `COUNT` in outer query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT c.*
  FROM c
  LEFT JOIN c2t ON c.id = c2t.cid
    AND NOW() BETWEEN COALESCE(dateStart, '0000-00-00')
    AND COALESCE(dateEnd, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  GROUP BY c2t.cid
  HAVING COUNT(c2t.id) > 0
) AS sub
```

Comment: just an improvement , Instead using count(*)  try to use a key in that table eg : count(primary_Key)  will improve your query performance  especially if you use innodb .

Comment: @csf would a wrapped SELECT benefit from an index in the subquery's table?

Comment: @willydee Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179969/what-is-better-in-mysql-count-or-count1 Query optimizer (at least in SQL Server world) is smart enough to get optimal plan between `COUNT(1)/COUNT(*)/COUNT(pk)`

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want returned is the number of c's who have active subscriptions, then you can simplify your query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS cnt
FROM c
INNER JOIN c2t ON c.id = c2t.cid
  AND NOW() BETWEEN COALESCE(dateStart, '0000-00-00')
    AND COALESCE(dateEnd, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

So, `INNER JOIN` is used in place of `LEFT JOIN`: there is no need to return c's with no matches in `c2t`, since these are not going to have any active subscriptions.

Also, there is no need to `GROUP BY`: the query returns just one row with the number of c's.

Finally, `DISTINCT` must be used in `COUNT` so as to avoid counting duplicate `c.id` values more than once.