# Getting a count(1) value to a list in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to get the count of a column in a table using a SQL query to a C# list

my sample code is below

```
"Select count(1) as Values, SM.Name from SM INNER JOIN Bill on SM.ID = Bill.AL INNER JOIN Details on Bill.ID = Details.ID"
```

I need to to add the count to a list<> Can some one tell me how to do that?

Since this count value doesn't have a column name I have given it the name "Values"
I have tried to get the value as following code

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post(Brands brand)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<Brands> list = new List<Brands>();
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con =
                    new SqlConnection(
                        "MyConnectionString");
                con.Open();
                    var query = "Select count(1) as Values, SM.Name from SM INNER JOIN Bill on SM.ID = Bill.AL INNER JOIN Details on Bill.ID = Details.ID";

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);   

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                adptr.Fill(dt);
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    Brands GetAll = new Brands();
                   GetAll.Count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Values"]);
                    GetAll.Name = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();

                    list.Add(GetAll);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return Ok(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `1` here, is that column name

Comment: COUNT takes a column name as the parameter. Not sure what you mean by Count(1)

Comment: @un-lucky count(1) is equal to count(*)

Comment: yup true . should I edit the question to count(*)

Comment: Can you also update with a screen shot or something of the resulting Data in the DataTable? I'm assuming you are trying to loop over the rows and get the count value for each row.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: I'm a beginner in C#. I dont know how to get the output of the data table. Sorry

Comment: @Kason. I need the count to be passed in to the list. But it wont happen. Thats my problem

Comment: Are you sure your SQL statement result is what you expected?  If true, could you show more C# code?

Comment: I have Edited the question with full code. Is this helpful @Kason

Comment: c# code looks fine to me

Comment: Which line of code throw an exception? Syntax or runtime?

Comment: Since the colum name is given in like 'Count(*) as Values' , by adding the name Value to the input in 'GetAll.Count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Values"]);' gives the resulting table?

Comment: There is no error in this code. I need to push the count in to the list. I wont to know how to do that. At the moment the list returns 0

Comment: you can get the rows using this : dt.Rows[i][0]; which 0 is columns index

Comment: I believe this line `Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Values"])` would not return 0. Does your SQL return no rows so that you never run the looping?

Comment: When I use this code with Select Name or Select ID it works fine. I wont to add the count(1) value just like the above to the resulting table.

Comment: try dt.Rows[i][0] instead of dt.Rows[i]["Values"]

Comment: Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' 

Is the error im getting when I add Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Values"])

Comment: got it. Let me check

Comment: @Kason Added it but nothing changed. Yes the loop runs but only once

Comment: Could you get the value of dt.Rows[i][0]? what is this

Comment: the list returns count = 0

Comment: No no. Im just putting some brake points and getting the value by moving the cursor

Comment: list returns count = 0 is means your sql query nothing

Comment: Now thats the problem. When I run the same query in SQL Server it gives a table as output. But here I get nothing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Every one for contributing to help me out. Special Thanks to @Kason. What I did was add `Group by` to SQL Query. That Solved the Issue. Hope this would be helpful to others.

Answer (score -1):

> I appriciate the efforsts and suggestion for all helpers,but some
>   comments are showing they have less knowledge of sql.
>
> ## 1)
>
> you used column(1), please never ever use this syntax for
>   query,this is bad practice to get data,always use name of column.
>
> ## 2)
>
> Someone posted that count(1) is equals to count(*) than it's
>   myth,because count(*) will provide count of all the rows where
>   count(1) will provide only count of that  which are not null. (Not
>   believing try this in your system.)
>
> keep this points in mind also
>   suggest to others,hope you like this post.

Comment: count(*) and count(1) also include null.

Comment: it may be your primary key field that why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179969/what-is-better-in-mysql-count-or-count1   if  your sql knowledge is not enough, please do more research.

Comment: @Kason the issue was not because of count(1) or count(*). It was just because of not having group by key word at the end of the sql query and Thanks for the support. I will look into this as well. Cheers