# How can I count selected rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM
    qanda q
        JOIN
    qanda a ON q.Id = a.related
WHERE
    a.type = 1
AND a.author_id = 29
AND q.amount IS NULL;
```

Now, it selects 3 rows in reality. Ok I want it returns `3` instead of `a.*`. Actually I don't need any valye of those columns, I just need to count the number of selected rows. How can I do that?

**Note:** I can use my current query and then count the number of rows by PHP. But I don't like that.

Comment: The answer below is probably your best solution. Your driver also should have a function for this, http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @chris85 Even if the driver supports it, you still have to have MySQL query and count the number of rows.

Comment: @Pachonk ...yea that's why the comment was prefaced with `The answer below is probably your best solution.`

Comment: Completely understood, I just wanted to make it clear that even though it's option is available, it would be less efficient. I didn't mean to come off mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple. Use `COUNT()` in MySQL

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.id) as count
FROM
    qanda q
        JOIN
    qanda a ON q.Id = a.related
WHERE
    a.type = 1
AND a.author_id = 29
AND q.amount IS NULL;
```

Comment: Just one thing, Why not `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(a.id)` ?

Comment: No reason. Personal preference.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179969/what-is-better-in-mysql-count-or-count1 for more details.