# Which is faster getting Count OR getting the Records in SQL or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a huge table with 500,000 rows in MySQL.

Which is faster,

- getting the number of rows in a table or
- getting all the data with 8 columns?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling MySQL from your ASP.net code, then the most efficient way by far to get a count of all records in a table is to do `SELECT COUNT(*)`, or something equivalent to this.  The reason is that returning all records takes a potentially huge amount of bandwidth.  If all you want is a count of all records, then you don't really care about the data in those records.

Besides bandwidth/network overhead, there is the cost of counting the records themselves.  Databases were designed with such aggregate operations in mind, application languages less so.

Comment: Cheers!!! @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have read somewhere that COUNT(id) is faster than COUNT(*); is it correct ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Good question, I don't know the answer.  Are you asking for MySQL or any SQL database in general?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Although MySQL, but shouldn't it apply for SQL in general ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It usually doesn't matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179969/what-is-better-in-mysql-count-or-count1 (also true for SQL Server).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks - but it is optimized for MyISAM only and when using a  single table in select. I think nowadays, lot of people have started using InnoDB, and in case of JOINs, it is better to use the specific id in the COUNT()