# How to check updated rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm a MySQL beginner. Does anybody know what the sql statment is to read how many recods their are in a MySql database? I don't want to display the records i just want to know how many records their are in my table.

Thanks

DJ

Comment: Have you google for your solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql count table rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893424/mysql-count-table-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(*)` to get count of records in your table,as given below

```
Select count(*) from your_table
```