# How to count the number of rows in database table using MySQLi Object-oriented

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT count name_id, name FROM TABLE WHERE tag1 in ('$tag1') OR tag2 in ('$tag1') $andor tag2 in ('$tag2') OR tag1 in ('$tag2') ORDER BY rating desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

And now, I want to echo the number of name_id. So, what to do?

Make new line something like this: `$sql = "SELECT count(name_id)`

```
echo $sql;
```

Comment: You could refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893424/count-table-rows

Comment: I cannot find answer to my question their.

Comment: Refer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655628/mysql-count-total-number-of-rows-in-php. Displaying your total number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want count the no of rows in the results

```
echo  count($result);
```

if you want retrive it using SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

You can include your conditions to this query and get the count of filtered data.
Read [**this**](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php) for your reference on SQL count

Comment: echo  count($result); always echo "1". And sorry, i do not understand, where to put that 2nd code ;/

Comment: @RahulGupta that mean it's retrieving only one row. check the answer for reference, DO you want retrieve only the count or the data also?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
select count(name_id) as namecount FROM TABLE WHERE tag1 in ('$tag1') OR tag2 in ('$tag1') $andor tag2 in ('$tag2') OR tag1 in ('$tag2') group by name_id ORDER BY rating desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

you need to use **group by**

Comment: did you try this ?@Rahul Gupta