# How to count the number of rows in MySQL using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code:

```
<?php

function result($conn) {
      global $number;

    $sql = 'SELECT movie_name FROM movie_info LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print " ". $row['movie_name'] . " <br> ";

    }
}
result($conn);
?>
```

I am really confused, how to count the number of rows in the table and print it?

Comment: Where are you trying to count? Where is `$number` used? `$conn->query` returns a result object, you should `fetch` it.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*)

Comment: I myself am new but I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893424/count-table-rows might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO - Num Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(movie_name)` (most reliable), or PDOs `rowCount()` (this might not always work; read the manual), there are many possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a PDO Object with a PDO connection to your database - 
(Let´s call it for example $con)
You can prepare a statement like

```
     $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT movie_name FROM movie_info LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0');

     // Then fire it up
     $stmt->execute();

     // Pick up the result as an array
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

     // Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
     for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){
         echo $result[$x]['movie_name'];
     }
```

The count($result) keeps your number of result

Comment: If you want to do your output and you need to know how many rows you have to do, I think this example is the easiest way. 
And a little side effect is that a for loop has a better performance than a foreach.

Comment: You just need to use 
$count = $stmt->rowCount(); to get the affected rows back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM movie_info
```

the code above will return the count of data stored in that table,

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my suggestion

```
$moviescount = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(`movie_name`) FROM `movie_info` LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0')->fetchColumn();
```

and

```
echo moviescount; // for example 10034
```