# How to get number of rows from table based on ID from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have an index.php page that spits out data from two tables on my database. The first table, `questions` contains one column for my QuestionID and looks like this:

```
qid
----
 1
 2
 3
```

The second table called `answers` contains two columns, one for my AnswersID and the other which links to my QuestionsID on the `questions` table, and it looks like this:

```
aid | aqid
----|-----
 1  |  3
 2  |  1
 3  |  1
```

So on my index.php page, I basically want to echo out every `qid` row from the `questions` table and beside it the *total number of answers* (`aid` rows from the `answers` table) *corresponding to each QuestionID*.
To put simply, the result I want achieved on my index.php page is this:

```
QuestionID: 1 / Answers: 2
QuestionID: 2 / Answers: 0
QuestionID: 3 / Answers: 1
```

But based on my current code I am having trouble achieving this result. It keeps echoing out the wrong number of rows for each table. This is the unwanted result I am getting:

```
QuestionID: 1 / Answers: 3
QuestionID: 2 / Answers: 3
QuestionID: 3 / Answers: 3
```

So how would I fix this to achieve the correct result? This is my current code:

```
<?php 
$sql = "
SELECT questions.*, GROUP_CONCAT(answers.aqid) AS aqid
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN answers
ON questions.qid=answers.aqid
GROUP BY questions.qid
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $qid = $row["qid"];
    $aqid = $row["aqid"];
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
?>
<div>
    QuestionID: <?php echo $qid; ?>
    <?php foreach($answers as $answer): ?>
        Answers: <?php echo $row_cnt; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) returns a concatenated string. You might be looking for [`count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893424/count-table-rows)

Comment: @showdev Nope. Tried count() - doesn't work.

Comment: I replaced group_concat() with count() and it just returns the exact same result

Comment: `count()` returns a row count, which will be stored in the `$aqid` variable. There's no need for `$row_cnt` or the `foreach`.

Comment: Ahh so that's where the error was. Thanks so much for pointing that out. Totally fixed my code and it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) returns a concatenated string. You might be looking for [`count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html).

Also, `count()` returns a row count.
There doesn't seem to be a need for `$row_cnt` or the `foreach`.

Here's an example:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        q.`qid`,
        COUNT(a.`aqid`) AS `answerCount`
    FROM `questions` q
    LEFT JOIN `answers` a
        ON a.`aqid` = q.`qid`
    GROUP BY q.`qid`
    ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <div>
      QuestionID: <?php echo $row["qid"]; ?>
      Answers: <?php echo $row["answerCount"]; ?>
    <div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Your advice earlier had easily fixed my code. Thanks greatly for the further explanation and for providing an example! (Apologies for doubting you earlier, complete mistake on my end.)

Comment: No worries! I overlooked the rest of your code at first glance.